# Non symmetric java compression

Tags: java, compression, inflate, deflate

I have a data sample:

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{120, 1, -67, -107, -51, 106, 20, 81, 16, -123, 107, 18, -51, -60, 31, -30, 117, -4, -53, -60, -123, 25, 70, 71, 23, -111, 89, 12, 8, -83, 49, 4, -14, -93, -63, 73, 32, 89, -55, -112, -123, 10, -30, 66, 69, -110, 69, -64, -107, -77, 8, -72, 21, 23, -82, 5, -97, -64, 55, -48, -73, -16, 97, 4, -3, 14, -23, -110, 75, 59, 125, 39, 8, -10, -123, 51, -73, -86, -85, -6, 84, -99, -22, -18, 59, 53, 51, 27, 2, 95, 7, 24, 95, -36, 97, 95, 9, 102, -17, 46, -101, -51, -81, 109, -82, -101, -43, 44, -100, 54, -5, -56, -11, 9, -128, 105, -81, -128, -42, -25, -109, 102, -121, -109, 102, 63, 107, 102, 75, 32, 94, 79, -66, -43, 109, -15, -57, 9, 91, -79, 55, -74, 111, -49, -71, 103, -51, 54, 13, 58, -42, 121, 112, 22, 76, 3, -15, 5, -32, -21, 20, 70, 0, -94, 19, -58, -59, -59, 19, -128, -81, 51, 24, 1, -8, -3, 23, -80, -107, 35, -1, 38, -104, -51, 109, 54, 123, -12, -6, -67, 54, -69, 1, 60, -57, 109, 122, 27, -34, -29, -70, 122, -68, 10, 2, 80, 111, -102, -45, 29, 16, -64, 1, 40, -6, 15, -71, -26, -15, 45, -20, 103, 5, -1, 65, -28, 95, -57, 126, 90, -16, -69, -111, -33, -64, 46, -6, 47, -93, -72, -6, -39, 3, -9, -127, -6, 92, -52, -9, 37, -10, 89, -96, -72, -18, -9, 62, 93, 91, 29, 109, 110, 19, 30, -34, -30, -57, -11, 23, 103, -12, -31, -21, 119, -94, -57, -97, 81, 32, -9, 54, 120, 12, -60, -21, -21, 87, -66, 120, 93, -84, 73, 70, -117, -89, -47, -78, -7, 100, 94, 11, 21, 77, 107, 48, -21, 70, 50, -81, 78, -4, 72, 113, -102, 79, 111, 64, -99, -38, 1, -108, -51, 76, -3, -118, -83, 5, -92, -61, -25, -12, 63, 103, -42, -50, -21, -92, 102, -74, 64, 39, 61, -69, 6, -82, 36, 103, -47, 67, -35, 2, 95, 77, 27, -92, -8, -26, -120, 31, 77, 54, -51, -41, -96, -26, 28, -75, -37, -96, 108, 102, -102, -105, -66, -45, 94, -82, -93, -118, -103, 101, -44, -46, -5, -107, -46, -72, 74, 70, -97, 39, -39, -25, 61, 74, -27, -11, -19, -100, -83, -14, 5, 101, 32, -107, -41, 37, -34, 33, -73, 51, -122, -81, 67, -51, 46, -75, 51, 80, 54, -77, 14, -67, 79, -125, 126, -82, -93, -118, -103, 109, 80, 75, 103, 89, 74, -29, 14, 25, 3, -69, 4, 102, -110, 121, 3, -101, -78, 29, -72, -60, -103, -30, 91, 38, -98, -111, -101, -115, -31, -53, -88, -71, 76, -19, 13, 80, 54, 51, 61, 115, -83, 1, -112, -114, 127, -103, 25, -57, -112, 40, -2, -36, 91, -117, 108, -98, -57, 95, 103, 126, -109, -8, 39, -32, 103, -70, -50, -20, -94, -1, 54, -118, 43, 95, 126, -103, 6, -113, 59, 79, 21, 26, -12, 31, 16, -9, 124, 119, -124, 31, 107, 80, 126, 74, -125, -57, -99, -89, 10, 13, -21, -123, -98, -73, 71, -8, -79, 6, -27, -89, 52, 120, -36, 121, -86, -48, -80, 91, -24, -7, -59, 8, 63, -42, -96, -4, -108, 6, -113, 59, -49, 113, 52, -52, -64, 121, 17, 104, 5, 32, -5, 55, -108, 74, -2, -44};
```

it's just a compressed EMF image. I try to decompress it by code:

```
    InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int length = 0;
    while ((length = iis.read(buf)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buf, 0, length);
    }
```

and get a CORRECT answer

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, -128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 118, 0, 0, 0, -93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 16, 0, 0, 127, 22, 0, 0, 32, 69, 77, 70, 0, 0, 1, 0, 16, 10, 0, 0, -110, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -96, 5, 0, 0, -124, 3, 0, 0, -4, 1, 0, 0, 62, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, -64, 7, 0, 60, -40, 4, 0, 67, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 108, 0, 69, 0, 77, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 109, -121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, -93, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 118, 0, 0, 0, -93, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 118, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 98, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 71, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 97, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 107, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 113, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 118, 0, 0, 0, -93, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -112, -79, -63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 45, 0, 33, 0, 39, 0, 33, 0, 32, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 24, 0, 25, 0, 18, 0, 16, 0, 18, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 7, 0, 45, 0, 16, 0, 45, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -112, -79, -63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 37, 0, 51, 0, 31, 0, 51, 0, 23, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 16, 0, 44, 0, 10, 0, 35, 0, 10, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 10, 0, 18, 0, 16, 0, 18, 0, 23, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 31, 0, 26, 0, 37, 0, 35, 0, 37, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -112, -79, -63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 57, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 68, 0, 40, 0, 76, 0, 33, 0, 76, 0, 24, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 15, 0, 68, 0, 8, 0, 57, 0, 8, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 8, 0, 38, 0, 15, 0, 38, 0, 24, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 33, 0, 47, 0, 40, 0, 57, 0, 40, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -112, -79, -63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 73, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 82, 0, 27, 0, 90, 0, 21, 0, 90, 0, 14, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 6, 0, 82, 0, 0, 0, 73, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 57, 0, 6, 0, 57, 0, 14, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 57, 0, 21, 0, 64, 0, 27, 0, 73, 0, 27, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 58, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 58, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 58, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 81, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 81, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 81, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -128, 59, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 92, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 92, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 92, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, -106, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, -128, 37, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 40, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0]
```

After that i'm try to compress it back by code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //Deflater defalter = new Deflater(1);
    DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos2);//deflater, false);
    dos.write(baos.toByteArray(), 0 , baos.toByteArray().length);
    dos.finish();
```

And get a  result:

```
[120, -100, -67, 84, 77, 47, 3, 81, 20, 61, -29, -85, 45, 13, -29, 91, 89, -48, -108, -78, 32, -77, -112, 72, -22, -93, 105, -126, -46, 40, 9, 43, 105, 44, -112, -120, 5, 34, 44, 36, 86, -70, -112, -40, -118, -123, -75, -60, 47, -16, 15, -8, 23, 126, -116, -124, 51, -45, -5, -30, -103, -52, -68, -63, 98, 94, 114, -46, 119, 122, -49, -36, 123, -49, 25, 106, 1, -88, -29, -5, 92, 17, -49, 26, 95, -74, -127, -101, 1, 96, 108, 117, -77, 12, 88, -80, -37, -127, 7, 126, -33, 68, -16, -118, 83, -47, 61, -75, 2, -73, -51, -64, -121, 5, 20, 45, -4, 56, -5, -81, 9, 44, -66, -73, 96, 25, -25, -72, -60, 17, -97, 89, -59, 38, -54, 94, -83, -101, 72, 19, 73, -23, 103, 107, -49, -91, -124, 91, -126, -88, 122, -38, 87, -17, -16, -43, 123, 69, -29, -34, 39, -119, 33, -71, -69, 103, -29, -20, -50, -5, -100, -48, 52, -22, -50, -35, -22, 11, -78, -29, -120, -12, 76, 73, 78, 115, -62, -81, 2, -8, -70, -58, -73, -120, 67, 31, 95, -45, -8, 56, 113, -32, -29, -114, -58, 123, 2, -8, -119, -58, -35, 125, 46, -120, 37, -39, 115, 81, 62, -117, -30, 51, 37, -49, -85, 61, -107, -73, 4, -67, -87, 59, 79, 125, -54, -112, -47, -3, -53, -37, -97, 50, 114, 49, 67, -20, 18, 83, -38, 123, -7, -108, -61, 63, 23, 100, -88, -56, 114, 82, 22, 99, 70, 93, -106, -101, 100, -24, -38, 38, 76, -70, -124, -105, -116, -69, -75, -71, -97, -21, 46, -63, -39, 54, 17, -106, 25, 36, -25, -84, -8, -120, 35, -77, -100, -44, 77, -69, 79, 83, 49, -117, 81, 98, -48, -88, -101, 101, -57, 105, -2, -41, -28, 8, -109, 110, -104, -11, 70, -78, -26, 126, 61, -100, 57, -52, -39, 57, 34, 44, 51, 55, -81, 118, 111, 118, -61, 71, 28, -103, 21, 100, 103, -45, -18, 43, -84, 84, -7, 38, -85, -100, 100, -46, 85, -47, 69, 109, -110, 61, -109, 70, -99, -61, 122, -98, -38, 124, 68, -65, 60, 103, 58, -84, 22, -120, -80, -52, -14, -62, -85, -46, 39, -114, -52, 42, 114, 55, -19, -66, 67, 69, 13, -3, 68, -89, 81, 87, 67, 27, -75, -115, -98, 38, 93, -55, 123, 87, 109, -124, -71, 95, -127, 51, 75, -100, 93, 33, -62, 50, 43, -56, 115, 53, -15, -15, -97, -52, 56, -18, 79, -103, 101, -120, 71, -4, -4, -115, -10, -13, 107, -115, 103, -124, -121, 121, 80, 117, -43, 39, 14, 15, -114, 111, -25, -7, 0, -82, 123, 112, 34, 60, -88, -70, -22, 19, -121, -121, -78, 111, -25, -19, 0, -82, 123, 40, 71, 120, 80, 117, -43, 39, 14, 15, 123, -66, -99, -113, 3, -72, -18, 97, 47, -62, -125, -86, -85, 62, -65, -15, -48, 73, -12, -55, -2, -74, -36, -65, 0, -108, 74, -2, -44]
```

the more similar result was achieved when i uncomment deflater initialization and using in DeflateOutputStream constructor.

As for me it's very strange behaviour or i don't use inflate/deflate mechanism properly.

Any idea?

Comment: Does the result you get deliver the same data when you decode it? Maybe there is more than one valid compression for your data.

Comment: hmmm...as i understand, if u r right - i need to inflate it twice too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lossless compressors, to be called such, assure that compression followed by decompression produces exactly the same thing as what you started with.

On the other hand, there is no assurance nor any need to assure that decompression followed by compression should always produce the same result.  Compressors can comply with the compressed data format, but produce very different results on the same input data depending the algorithm used and parameters of the algorithm that are chosen.  Compressors often have different compression "levels" that allow the user to spend more or less CPU compressing better or worse, depending on the application.  So you will get different output with different settings.

Comment: as i know Inflater and Deflater use the same algo and the same parameters. I mentioned about the creation of non-standart Deflater in the main question but it's still magic for me